# Align divs horizontally even if off-screen

Tags: css

I'm trying to line up divs horizontally, even if they go off-screen. Im using display: box;

```
<div id="container">   
   <div class="box">
       1
   </div>
   <div class="box">
       2
   </div>
   ....
   ....
</div>

.box{
    background-color: #7f94a7;
    color: #fff;
    height: 5.2rem;
    width: 6rem;
    display:table;
}

#container{
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-box;
}
```

Check out the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p5tebcua/2/).

This works fine in chrome but in internet explorer 10, the box are aligned vertically....

Comment: Try with `-ms-` prefix for IE10 http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox and `flexbox`instead of box

Comment: and the `-moz-box` for firefox.. or just use the standard only and include [Prefix free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) in the page to auto-apply the vendor prefixes

Comment: usung -ms-box didnt work...

Comment: @mark it is `-ms-flexbox`

Comment: Change `display:box;` to `display:inline-box;` and use `overflow:hidden;` on the containing div.

Comment: I don't say `-ms-box`  please refer to the link I provide you and the notes for IE10 you need the new syntax flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `display: box;` to `display: inline-box;` and use `overflow:` to keep or hide run-off from being visible.

As stated above, `white space: nowrap;` on content fixes issue.

CSS:

```
.box{
background-color: #7f94a7;
color: #fff;
height: 5.2rem;
width: 6rem;
display: inline-block;
}

#container{
display: box;
display: -webkit-box;
overflow-x: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: keep extra run-off from being visible --- The OP doesn't want that

Comment: Let me make sure I understand before I edit. You want boxes side-by-side no matter the number of boxes and you want them all visible? Is that correct @Mark before I edit answer?

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what the `display:table` is supposed to do on the `.box` class -- there aren't any cells or rows inside of it, so it isn't table-like at all. The table box sizing model is made to flex the width of the cells. Take a look at this example to see `display:table` in action... resize the output panel to see what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/vz33sfwc/

```
.box{
    display:table-cell;
}
#container{
    display:table;
}
```

It sounds like you actually want the boxes to NOT flex, but to go off-screen. To do that, we'll set the boxes to use `display:inline-block` -- this makes them sit next to one another on a single line. Then, we tell the container how to treat white space for the inline elements with `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.box{
    display: inline-block;
}
#container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See it in action here, again resizing the output panel for the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/k9yp05mj/ -- notice we get a horizontal scrollbar and the boxes do not flex in size.

**Documentation**

- CSS `whitespace` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space
- CSS `display` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

try just with "`display : inline`" for the child div.keep width auto i.e depending on content it'll adjust  Check the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/invincibleJai/p5tebcua/45/

Code:

```css
.box{
    background-color: #7f94a7;
    color: #fff;
    height: 5.2rem;
    width: 6rem;
    display:inline;
    padding:0.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">   
    <div class="box">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        6
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        7
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        8        
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        9
    </div><div class="box">
        10
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        11
    </div><div class="box">
        12
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        13
    </div>
</div>
```